# What happens to digits after the decimal point?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have float `Test = Convert.ToSingle((125 * 100) / 149);` line in my C# application. I expect to get 83.89 as result but I get only 83 as seen in the picture below.

Besides, if I say `MessageBox.Show(Test.ToString("0.00"));` my Visual Studio 2015 instance crushes in Debug mode and restarts itself.

What can be the reason? Where is the decimal part of the float number?

[image]

Comment: You are performing integer arithmetic. You'll only get integers out of it. Change at least one of the numbers to a floating-point number, i.e. `(125.0 * 100) / 149`, and the `int`s will be converted to floating-point.

Comment: @Glorin Oakenfoot you are right. I was thinking that floating-point is default fur such operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably not getting those values out of the blue. So declare them (optionally including some comments to refrain from *magic numbers*):

```
value = 125;           // Previously declared as float
int factor = 100;      // Standard multiplier.
int divisor = 149;     // Process factor.
float test = Convert.ToSingle(value) * factor / divisor;

// result: 83.89262
```